# Jquery- getting image dimensions in a .each loop?

Tags: jquery, image, dimensions, each

I'm trying to write some code that will print out the dimensions of all images contained in a div, simple as it seems I can't get it working. Could anyone point out the errors here?
Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var width = 0;
  var height = 0;
  var hello = "hello";

  $('#imagebox img').each(function(){

    width = $(this).width;
    height = $(this).height;
    $('#main').append(hello);
    $('#main').append(width);
    $('#main').append(height);    
  });

});
```

[JSBin Example Here](http://jsbin.com/ikoge5/13/edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

width and height are functions. Try:

```
width = $(this).width();
height = $(this).height();
```

Comment: +1 Or better yet, `var $this = $(this); width = $this.width(); height = $this.height();` (as jQuery has to do several function calls and a memory allocation every time you call `$()`).

Comment: what a rookie error hehe. thanks for the help (and the optimisation tip TJ) :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no attributes `widht` and `height`. What you can do is

```
width = $(this).css('width');
```

or

```
width = $(this).width();
```

and similarly for height.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this after the image has fully loaded.

To do this, can place the code in a `.load()` handler.

```
var main = $('#main');

$('#imagebox img').load(function(){
  var $th = $(this);
  width = $th.width();
  height = $th.height();
  main.append((hello + width) + height);   
});
```

or if you want to make sure that the image dimensions are appended in the proper order, then do it on `window` load.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var main = $('#main');

    var vals = $('#imagebox img').map(function(){
      var $th = $(this);
      width = $th.width();
      height = $th.height();
      return (hello + width) + height;   
    }).get();

    main.append( vals.join('') );
});
```

Comment: As a side note, this technique wouldn't necessarily output the widths and heights in the same order as the images are positioned on the page, just in the order of which loaded first. Might be useful to the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your version to

- use the proper methods for height and
  width
- stop re-querying the DOM for the same
  elements over and over
- stop calling append repeatedly

See http://jsbin.com/ikoge5/15/edit

Comment: more neat optimisation, great, grazie!